# Search with fragment of a string in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have PHP array defined like this:

```
 {
  "data": [
    {
      "content": "Build your communication",
      "property": null,
      "name": "description"
    },
    {
      "content": "simplify it",
      "property": "og:title",
      "name": null
    },
    {
      "content": "unleash the effectiveness",
      "property": "og:description",
      "name": null
    },
    {
      "content": "https:\/\/uploads-ssl.webflow.com\/\/%%20SETTINGS.png",
      "property": "og:image",
      "name": null
    }
}
```

How can I search trough *property* keys and return just array groups where property field with values **og:** as a part of the string is defined.

```
    $crawler = new Crawler(file_get_contents($url));
    $items = $crawler->filter('meta');

    $metaData = [];
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $itemCrawler = new Crawler($item);
        $content     = $itemCrawler->eq(0)->attr('content');
        $property    = $itemCrawler->eq(0)->attr('property');
        $name        = $itemCrawler->eq(0)->attr('name');

        $metaData = [
            'content' => $content,
            'property' => $property,
            'name' => $name,
        ];
    }
    
    return $metaData;;
```

Tried with :

```
if(substr( $data['property'], 0, 3 ) === 'og:') {}
```

Returns just first one.

Can someone help?

Comment: The code you posted has syntax errors and shouldn't be running at all.

Comment: Also, what is `$items`?

Comment: It's a method returning my data. It's wowking. I edited code. @El_Vanja

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't precise enough - is `$items` the whole array you've shown at the beginning of the question? Or is it just the subarray under the `data` index? What about the syntax errors? Are these present in your actual code?

Comment: No problem. :) It's subarray under data index. For now, I don't have any syntax errors. @El_Vanja

Comment: Alright, so then this boils down to identifying whether the property string contains the substring `og:`. That shouldn't be too hard to look for.

Comment: And about the syntax errors, the code you posted in the question is full of them. Did you rewrite this by hand when you were writing the question? It's always best to copy actual code.

Comment: I wrote it by hand. Now it's copied. I wanted to simplify it. :) Edited. @El_Vanja

Comment: something like [this](https://3v4l.org/UuFp8) might help you solve your issue.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you. $ret will hold all objects where the property "property" contains "og:".

```
    $items = json_decode('{
  "data": [
    {
      "content": "Build your communication",
      "property": null,
      "name": "description"
    },
    {
      "content": "simplify it",
      "property": "og:title",
      "name": null
    },
    {
      "content": "unleash the effectiveness",
      "property": "og:description",
      "name": null
    },
    {
      "content": "https:\/\/uploads-ssl.webflow.com\/\/%%20SETTINGS.png",
      "property": "og:image",
      "name": null
    }
    ]}');

$ret = array_filter($items->data, function($item) {
    return strstr($item->property, "og:");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$data = [];
    foreach ($items["data"] as $item) {
        $content     = item['content'];
        $property    = item['property'];
        $name        = item['name'];
    $temp= [
        'content' => $content,
        'property' => $property,
        'name' => $name,
    ];
array_push($data,$temp);
    }
```

You have a "data" keyword before the array. Try this

Comment: Aside from not fixing all the issues with OP's code, this doesn't even attempt to answer the question of filtering the elements.